# Quadruple index and the existence of corner state

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, topology, topological-insulators, topological-order

I have been following [this paper](https://scholar.google.com.hk/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=zh-CN&user=ZGvCd0IAAAAJ&sortby=pubdate&citation_for_view=ZGvCd0IAAAAJ:rOcdG6UcVlcC), which seems to discuss the connection between corner state and a quadruple index calculated $q(k_z)$ by equation (3) of it. At two special point $k_z=0 /\pi$, the index will be $Z_2$ quantized as either $0$ or $\frac{1}{2}$. And it is said that a $\frac{1}{2}$ quantization is non-trivial, and would imply the existence of corner state in that case.

Let me be clear, the Hamiltonian is given by the equation in Appendix A, (A1). I am only conerned with $V_1$ and $V_2$ term. $k_z$ should be viewed as a parameter rather than a momentum, so it is really a Hamiltonian of a 2D square lattice with 4 internal degrees of freedom. And there are various hopping terms around.

However, when I try to reproduce the result, I find that when $L_x=L_y$ are odd, where $L_x$ and $L_y$ are the system's size along x and y direction, I find my result agree with the statement, i.e. when $q(k_z)$ is $\frac{1}{2}/0$, there are/aren't corner states. When $L_x=L_y$ are even, I find exactly the opposite, i.e. when $q(k_z)$ is $\frac{1}{2}/0$, there aren't/ are corner states.

**Does anyone might have an idea what is going on here? Why would the result depend whether the size of the system is odd/even?** I am more or less sure that my Hamiltonian written in the real basis are correct. I paste my way of producing the Hamiltonian in the real basis as follwoing:

Let us first write the Hamiltonian in k space, where the Hamiltonian is given by that in the appendix, the QASH. we shall denote it as $H(k_x,k_y)$. $k_z$ is ignored as it is just a parameter for calculating q. For $L_x=L_y$ even/odd, the allowed wave vectors are
$$
k_i=2\pi \frac{n}{L_i} \quad n_i=\frac{L_i}{2}...-\frac{L_i-2}{2} (even) \quad n_i=\frac{L_i-1}{2}...-\frac{L_i-1}{2} (odd)
$$
We will use Greek letter to denote the internal degrees of freedom, of which there are 4. We use m and n to denote real space position, i.e. $|m,n,\mu>$ denotes the atom located at (m,n) with internal DOF $\mu$. m and n goes from 1 to $L_x$, $\mu$ does from 1 to 4. We use k to denote k space basis, i.e. $|k_x,k_y,\mu>$.
Since we have $H(k_x,k_y)$, which is a 4-by-4 matrix, that is, we know what the following terms look like.

$$
<k_x,k_y,\mu|H|k'_x,k'_y,\nu>\equiv H_{(k_x,k_y,\mu),(k_x,k_y,\nu)}\delta_{(k_x,k_y),(k_x',k_y')}\\
H(k_x,k_y)_{\mu\nu}=<k_x,k_y,\mu|H|k_x,k_y,\nu>
$$

Notice that the transformation between the real space basis and the k space basis is given by

$$
U_{(m,n,\mu),(k_x,k_y,\nu)}\equiv <m,n,\mu|k_x,k_y,\nu>=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L_xL_y}}e^{ik_xm}e^{ik_yn}
$$

Then we know that the Hamiltonian in the real basis is given by

$$H_{(m,n,\mu),(m',n',\nu)}=\sum_{(k_x,k_y,\mu'),(k_x',k_y',\nu')}U_{(m,n,\mu),(k_x,k_y,\mu')}H_{(k_x,k_y,\mu'),(k_x',k_y',\nu')}<k_x',k_y',\nu'|m',n',\nu>$$
$$=\sum_{(k_x,k_y,\mu'),(k_x',k_y',\nu')}U_{(m,n,\mu),(k_x,k_y,\mu')}H_{(k_x,k_y,\mu'),(k_x',k_y',\nu')}<m',n',\nu|k_x',k_y',\nu'>^*$$
$$=\sum_{(k_x,k_y,\mu'),(k_x',k_y',\nu')}U_{(m,n,\mu),(k_x,k_y,\mu')}H_{(k_x,k_y,\mu'),(k_x',k_y',\nu')}$$
$$=U^{\dagger}_{(k_x',k_y',\nu'),(m',n',\nu)}$$
$$=(UH_kU^{\dagger})_{(m,n,\mu),(m',n',\nu)}$$

That is, the Hamiltonian written under real basis is $H_{R}=UH_kU^{\dagger}$,
where $H_k$ denotes Hamiltonian under k basis, which is obtained by stacking the 4-by-4 $H(k_x,k_y)$ along the diagonal.
$$H_k\equiv \oplus_{(k_x,k_y)} H(k_x,k_y)$$

The $H_R$ obtained in this way is under periodic boundary condition. To obtain open boundary condition, we do the following thing:

In matlab, we do for loops over $(m,n,\mu)$ and $(m',n',\nu)$, whenever we find $|m-m'|+|n-n'|>5$ (this is arbitrary, just don't make it too small or too large), we set $H_{(m,n,\mu),(m',n',\nu)}$ to 0.

Comment: When you say you're comparing odd/even lattices sizes, do you mean you are including an odd/even number of four-site unit cells, or do you mean you are cutting unit cells in half?

Comment: No. In one unit cell, there is only one atom, but each atom has 4 degrees of freedom. I understand you are saying something like graphene, where 2 degrees of freedom refers to two sublattices. But here there are no sublattices, it is just ordinary square lattice. When I say odd/even, I mean odd/even number of unit cells, so there are no cutting of unit cells.

Comment: So much for an easy answer! I agree that is unexpected behavior. This doesn't happen in the usual Benalcazar-Bernevig-Hughes model of topological quadrupoles.